# How can we have a ProjectionExpression on a key that is an integer

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have a scenario where The data is structured such as this.

```json
{
  "PartitionKey": "foobar",
  "SomeDict": {
    "10": "a value",
    "20": "another value",
    ...
  }
}
```

I want to have a projection expression to only read one of the values. The "naive" way would be to do the following query:

```
get_item(
  Key={"PartitionKey": "foobar"},
  ProjectionExpression="SomeDict.10"
)
```

But it fails with the following error: `An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the GetItem operation: Invalid ProjectionExpression: Syntax error; token: "10", near: ".10"`

Is there a way to have projection expressions on keys that are integers, or is that a limitation?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the docs:

> You can use any attribute name in a projection expression, provided
> that the first character is a-z or A-Z and the second character (if
> present) is a-z, A-Z, or 0-9. If an attribute name does not meet this
> requirement, you must define an expression attribute name as a
> placeholder.

You need to provide `ExpressionAttributeNames`.  To add to your example it would be something like:

```
get_item(
  Key={"PartitionKey": "foobar"},
  ProjectionExpression="#somedict.#ten",
  ExpressionAttributeNames={"#somedict":"SomeDict", "#ten":"10"}
)
```

[Read more here from the Amazon DynamoDB docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.ProjectionExpressions.html)

Comment: I should have thought of it... :) Thank you!